# Deleted the _replicator database

Tags: database, cloudant

I'm learning how to use Cloudant and accidentally deleted the _replicator database. I've searched through documents but I don't see anything about being able to recreate the _replicator database. Is there a way I can recreate it?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able recreate it by the normal method of creating databases.

With curl :

```
https://username:password@username.cloudant.com/_replicator -X PUT
```

Comment: Contacted support and apparently there were some nodes on my cluster that were down for maintenance. I wasn't able to create any databases let alone the replicator. The nodes are back up, so everything is working again now. Thanks!